# MVC - Input submit causing redirect automatically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following form

```
<form id="file_upload" action="/Upload/Save" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" id="txtProposalName" name="name" placeholder="Nome da Camiseta" />
<input type="text" id="txtProposalDesc" name="description" placeholder="Descrição da Camiseta"/>
<div class="fileupload-buttonbar">
    <div class="progressbar fileupload-progressbar"></div>
    <span class="fileinput-button">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="upload-image">Upload images</a>
        <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple />
    </span>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="imgID" name="imgID"/>
<input type="submit" id="postProposal"/>
```

Would call this action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Save(string name, string description, string imgID)
    {
        return Json("a");
    }
```

(This is the current implementation, it has no logic because I am still testing some things).

My problem is: when I click on my submit button, the action is called with the correct values, but when it returns, my browser redirects to /Upload/Save (which is the action URL).
Why is this happening? Is there any way to prevent it?

Thanks!

Comment: of course it will go. `action="/Upload/Save"` this is causing it. remove the action and and if you want to upload via ajax, use your javascript to send the file(s) to your action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an asynchronous call to your method (e.g. AJAX) to prevent the page from reloading.

Comment: Marking as answer because this is going to be my approach, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As I can see you use full page reload with:

```
    action="/Upload/Save"
```

Also you trying to post data to json action method in controller. You need all form submit make with jquery, most problems you will find with ajax file uploaders.

**Added:**
Also look at [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) it will help you to collect all form input values.

Comment: "You need all form submit make with jquery, most problems you will find with ajax file uploaders." Sorry, I could not understand what you meant.

Comment: I add link for inputs, but for ajax file upload look this links: [How can I upload files asynchronously with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery) and [jQuery Ajax File Upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Ajax.BeginForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) to prevent reload page.

Comment: I will try this in some minutes and let you know :)

Comment: In this scenario it cant upload file [File upload using AJAX BeginForm](http://forums.asp.net/t/1450881.aspx/1)

Answer (score 0):

Dont need to prevent it, just **redirect** the user in your server code .

Comment: But I would like to stay on the same page (the same behavior that I would have when doing this post using javascript)....

Comment: use $.ajax('post', f...) function, and prevent the submit event from jummping to other URL.